# Know from which class it comes

Tags: java, class

I'm sending info from 2 Java classes to another Java class but I want to make an if/else situation where if it comes from 1 class enter in the if, if it comes from the other enter the else.

I'd be honest, I have certainly no idea how to do this so I couldn't even start it...

What i'm sending in both cases is this:

```
save.setCode(rtx);
```

Comment: How is the "sending info" achieved?

Comment: Paste your sample code...

Comment: Have you tried `info.getClass()`?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Methods normally should not care from where they are called. This sounds like you're creating yourself a bowl of [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

Comment: Post your code, so that people can provide better solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got this right, what you're trying to do is make some decision based on who is the caller of your class rather than on the information that was passed.

For this, you need to either:

1. Send some extra information within your argument list.
2. If you want this to be really dynamic (although I would strongly recommend against this approach), the only choice would be to have a look at the stack trace (via `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`).

Comment: I've must have explained myself badly what i'm sending is a string from one class to another with save.setCode(rtx); (for example) and i want to know where it come from. And yeah regardless the information taht has been passed

Comment: That confirms my guess. Well, if your logic depends on some extra information, make that part of the method signature: `setCode(String code, Context context)`, where `Context` is whatever kind of info you want to rely on. To check the stack trace and figure out the actual caller is slow, error-prone and not compatible with proper OO design.

Comment: Oh wow... that's definetly made it work... Mulțumesc mult!

Comment: I would give you a vote up, but I don't have 15 reputation, this is my first question around here....

Answer (score 3):

Use `instanceOf` of operator.

```
if (myobject instanceof Class1) {
    // then do your logic here
}

if (myobject instanceof Class2) {
    // then do your logic here
}
```

According to [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

> The instanceof operator compares an object to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending an object instance, then you can use `instanceof` operator to check if that object belongs to a particular class -

```
if (myobject instanceof MyClass1) {
    // then do your thing
}
else if (myobject instanceof MyClass2) {
    // then do your thing
}
```

But this is strongly discouraged. Use Polymorphism to achieve this kinds of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Faster than `instanceof`will be to use `toString()`

Answer (score 0):

***You must try this.
Explanation:
While sending `rtx` to the receiver class, you must also pass a key int which represent your sending class. I use this method only.***

```
public class Sender1
{
    Receiver save;Object rtx;
    public void somefunc(){

        final int Me=100;

        save.setCode(rtx, Me);
    }
}
public class Sender2
{
    Receiver save;Object rtx;
    public void somefunc(){

        final int Me=200;

        save.setCode(rtx, Me);
    }
}
public class Receiver{
    public void setCode(Object arg, int sender){
        final int Sender1=100, Sender2=200;
        if(sender==Sender1){
            ...
        }
        else if(sender==Sender2){
            ...
        }
        else ...
    }
}
```